# Show that two circles tangent to each other can always be mapped by a mobius transformation to the pair of parallel lines Im(z) =1 and Im(z) = -1

Tags: complex-analysis

I was able to map two circles to two lines parallel to the real axis that depended on the radii of the two circles, but I can't get these two lines specifically. Any help?

Comment: If you already two parallel lines then you can map those to $\operatorname{Im}(z) = \pm 1$ with a translation and a scaling.

Comment: So let's say I sent one to Im(z) = 1 and another to Im(z) = 1/2. How do I get Im(z) = 1 and Im(z) = -1 with just a translation and a scaling? Having trouble seeing it.

Comment: Never mind, I think I see it. Subtract 3/4 and multiply by 4. But is this always possible?

Comment: Never mind, figured that out too. Can't believe I didn't see it before. Thanks for the virtual slap-upside-the-head mate.